# Re-arranging a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have annual country data for different variables which is in CSV file. The data has many countries and regions. Below is just a simple example how the data looks like for the first five rows.

```
region   LAM    LAM    LAM    LAM  LAM  LAM 
country  Brazil Brazil Brazil Peru Peru Peru
variable FC     FP     FCO    FC   FP   FCO 
1850     10     20     30     15   25   16  
1851     10     20     30     15   25   16
```

Once I read in the CSV file as a data frame in R, I would like to transform it as below to make it easy to work with.

```
region country  year   variable amount
LAM    Brazil   1850    FC     10  
LAM    Brazil   1851    FC     10
LAM    Brazil   1850    FP     20
LAM    Brazil   1850    FP     20
LAM    Brazil   1850    FCO    30 
LAM    Brazil   1850    FCO    30 
LAM    Peru     1850    FC     15
```

Does anyone know the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Is that a data frame? Are `region, country, ...` rownames? Please share a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: You might want to use the transpose function, which is `t()`, if that doesn't work then you will want to use reshape2 or tidyr packages

Comment: Hi Sotos, this is just an example of how the CSV file looks like. So this will be different when you read it as a dataframe in R.  The first 3 rows, region, country and variable are actually row names. The subsequent rows are as as they are, with each row having the data for each year. Does this make it more understandable?

Comment: not really...just read it in your  session and use `dput(head(your_df))` to share it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

(df <- fread("
region   LAM    LAM    LAM    LAM  LAM  LAM 
country  Brazil Brazil Brazil Peru Peru Peru
variable FC     FP     FCO    FC   FP   FCO 
1850     10     20     30     15   25   16  
1851     10     20     30     15   25   16",  header = FALSE))

df <- setnames(transpose(df), df[, V1]) # transpose df and set col names, where the first column of df is the var names. 

df <- df[-1, ] # then our df is df without the first row

df_long <- melt(df, id.vars = c("region", "country", "variable"), variable.name = "year", value.name = "amount")

df_long

    region  country variable year amount
1     LAM  Brazil       FC   1850     10
2     LAM  Brazil       FP   1850     20
3     LAM  Brazil      FCO   1850     30
4     LAM    Peru       FC   1850     15
5     LAM    Peru       FP   1850     25
6     LAM    Peru      FCO   1850     16
7     LAM  Brazil       FC   1851     10
8     LAM  Brazil       FP   1851     20
9     LAM  Brazil      FCO   1851     30
10    LAM    Peru       FC   1851     15
11    LAM    Peru       FP   1851     25
12    LAM    Peru      FCO   1851     16
```

Comment: Any reason you're switching between `data.table` and `data.frame` like you're doing here?

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 It's just to read in the example data via `fread`, read.table not flexible enough.

Comment: But if you've read it in using `data.table`, then you might as well do the rest of the steps, including `melt`, using `data.table`...

Comment: I updated my answer, uses now completely data.table.

Answer (score 1):

```
as_tibble(t(df)) %>%  #Transpose the df
  janitor::row_to_names(1) %>% #put the first row as column names
  pivot_longer(c(`1850`,`1851`),names_to = "date",values_to="value") #pivot the df to make it tidier
```

Something like this gives :

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   region country variable date  value
   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>    <chr> <chr>
 1 LAM    Brazil  FC       1850  10   
 2 LAM    Brazil  FC       1851  10   
 3 LAM    Brazil  FP       1850  20   
 4 LAM    Brazil  FP       1851  20   
 5 LAM    Brazil  FCO      1850  30   
 6 LAM    Brazil  FCO      1851  30   
 7 LAM    Peru    FC       1850  15   
 8 LAM    Peru    FC       1851  15   
 9 LAM    Peru    FP       1850  25   
10 LAM    Peru    FP       1851  25   
11 LAM    Peru    FCO      1850  16   
12 LAM    Peru    FCO      1851  16
```

I've loaded your table with `read_csv2("your working directory",col_names=F)`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your data is more or less this way (it is useful, as Sotos said, to share reproducible examples):

```
mm <- matrix(
    c("region", "LAM",    "LAM",    "LAM",    "LAM",  "LAM",  "LAM", 
      "country", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Peru", "Peru", "Peru",
      "variable", "FC",     "FP",     "FCO",    "FC",   "FP",   "FCO", 
      "1850",   10,     20,     30,     15,   25,   16,
      "1851",  10,     20,     30,     15,   25,   16),
    byrow = TRUE,
    ncol = 7)

varnames <- mm[,1]  # to have variable names

mm <- t(mm) # we transpose it

mm <- as.data.frame(mm) # as data frame

colnames(mm) <- varnames # we set variable names

mm <- mm[-1, ] # this first row should not be there, 
               # probably this would be different as you import from a csv

library(tidyr)

mm <- pivot_longer(data = mm,
               cols = c("1850", "1851"),
               names_to = "year",
               values_to = "amount")
```

I think this is what you are looking for

```
mm
# A tibble: 12 x 5

   region country variable year  amount
   <fct>  <fct>   <fct>    <chr> <fct> 
 1 LAM    Brazil  FC       1850  10    
 2 LAM    Brazil  FC       1851  10    
 3 LAM    Brazil  FP       1850  20    
 4 LAM    Brazil  FP       1851  20    
 5 LAM    Brazil  FCO      1850  30    
 6 LAM    Brazil  FCO      1851  30    
 7 LAM    Peru    FC       1850  15    
 8 LAM    Peru    FC       1851  15    
 9 LAM    Peru    FP       1850  25    
10 LAM    Peru    FP       1851  25    
11 LAM    Peru    FCO      1850  16    
12 LAM    Peru    FCO      1851  16
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a function like one of the following. I've listed the functions from fastest to slowest on a test of a csv file that, when transposed, would result in a 53 column, 100000 row dataset. One of the `read_transposed` options would be faster on smaller datasets.

All of these use `fread`, so make sure you have a `library(data.table)` in your code.

## `csvtool` + `fread`

`csvtool` has a very fast `transpose` operation that can then be quickly read using `fread`.

```
fread_csvtool <- function(infile, header = TRUE, ...) {
  fread(cmd = sprintf("cat %s | csvtool transpose - | cat", infile), header = header, ...)
}
```

## `fread` + further processing (1)

```
read_transposed_1 <- function(infile) {
  temp <- fread(file = infile, header = FALSE)
  setnames(transpose(temp[, -1]), temp[[1]])[, lapply(.SD, type.convert)]
}
```

## `fread` + further processing (2)

```
read_transposed_2 <- function(infile) {
  temp <- lapply(fread(file = infile, sep = "\n", header = FALSE)$V1, function(x) {
    scan(what = "", text = x, sep = ",", quiet = TRUE)
  })
  setnames(setDT(lapply(temp, function(x) type.convert(x[-1L]))),
           vapply(temp, '[', character(1L), 1L))[]
}
```

After the data have been read, you can use your preferred method for converting the wide dataset into a long dataset. Since these all result in a `data.table`, I'd suggest:

```
melt(the_output, id.vars = 1:3)
```

---

## DEMO

### Sample data

```
x <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv")
writeLines(c("region,LAM,LAM,LAM,LAM,LAM,LAM",
             "country,Brazil,Brazil,Brazil,Peru,Peru,Peru",
             "variable,FC,FP,FCO,FC,FP,FCO",
             "1850,10,20,30,15,25,16",
             "1851,10,20,30,15,25,16"), x)

fread_csvtool(x)
##    region country variable 1850 1851
## 1:    LAM  Brazil       FC   10   10
## 2:    LAM  Brazil       FP   20   20
## 3:    LAM  Brazil      FCO   30   30
## 4:    LAM    Peru       FC   15   15
## 5:    LAM    Peru       FP   25   25
## 6:    LAM    Peru      FCO   16   16

melt(fread_csvtool(x), id.vars = 1:3, variable.name = "year", value.name = "amount")
##     region country variable year amount
##  1:    LAM  Brazil       FC 1850     10
##  2:    LAM  Brazil       FP 1850     20
##  3:    LAM  Brazil      FCO 1850     30
##  4:    LAM    Peru       FC 1850     15
##  5:    LAM    Peru       FP 1850     25
##  6:    LAM    Peru      FCO 1850     16
##  7:    LAM  Brazil       FC 1851     10
##  8:    LAM  Brazil       FP 1851     20
##  9:    LAM  Brazil      FCO 1851     30
## 10:    LAM    Peru       FC 1851     15
## 11:    LAM    Peru       FP 1851     25
## 12:    LAM    Peru      FCO 1851     16
```

### A larger test dataset

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 100001
years <- 50
X1 <- replicate(3, stringi::stri_rand_strings(n, 5), FALSE)
X2 <- replicate(years, runif(n), FALSE)
transposed_data <- data.table(t(cbind(as.data.table(X1), as.data.table(X2))))
transposed_data[, V1 := c(paste0("Var", 1:3), 1850:(1850+years-1))]
fwrite(transposed_data, file = "transposed.csv", col.names = FALSE)

fread_csvtool("transposed.csv")
```